# JS: construction of ndarrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

When I create a new [ndarray](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray) like this:

```
var my_array = [1,2,3];
var my_ndarray = ndarray( my_array, [3,1] );
```

will `my_ndarray` then contain a *reference* to or a *copy* of `my_array`?

Comment: That's easy to check. After _ndarraying_, change the actual array's value and check if copied array reflect changes. `var my_array = [1,2,3];
var my_ndarray = ndarray( my_array, [3,1] ); my_array[1] = 'Hello World!'; console.log(my_ndarray);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses a reference.

```
var ndarray = require("ndarray")
var arr = [1, 0, 0, 1];
var nArr = ndarray(arr);
console.log(nArr.data); // [1, 0, 0, 1]
arr.push(2);
console.log(nArr.data); // [1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```